# Автодополнение в bash не работает должным образом

Tags: linux, bash, autocomplete

автодополнение в `bash` не работает должным образом. когда я пишу `apt\<tab>`, автозаполенение работает нормально, но если написать к примеру `arpspoof\<tab>`, то вместо подсказок показывается файлы в текущей папке(хотя файлы для автозаполнения есть), свои скрипты для автозаполнения тоже не работают. я пытался: `sudo apt install --reinstall bash-completion`, `sudo apt install --reinstall bash`, но это не помогло (хотел попробовать перейти на `zsh`, но тут возникла другая проблема-когда прописываю `zsh` в консоль, просто ничего не происходит, и я не могу выполнить настройку)

```
bash версия 5.2.2(1)-release  
версия ядра Debian 6.0.12-1kali1
```

Comment: Ну видимо для arpspoof просто никто не написал правила автодополнения, если вам принципиально - напишите их сами

Comment: @andreymal, да вроде как написали: https://github.com/scop/bash-completion/blob/master/completions/arpspoof // автору вопроса: `Debian 6` — ну вы бы ещё про динозавров спросили — почему они компьютерами не пользовались. // `kali` — о! только сейчас заметил. нда, это пройдёт: время лечит…